# Limiting string length in regex

Tags: java, regex

I am just a beginner in java regex and I want to restrict a search to find a pattern of a particular length (eg:6) with the conditions below

```
[1-3][0-2][xs0][30Aa][xsu][.,]{6} or ^[1-3][0-2][xs0][30Aa][xsu][.,]$
```

Both the expressions give different results.Shouldn't both return the same output?
eg: `2203s.` is false for the first but true for the second.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `{6}` in `[.,]{6}` only quantifies `[.,]`, these regexps are not identical. I guess you are using them with `matches()`, right?

Comment: Yes. If I remove {6} ,will it restrict the search to strings of length 6? (It will still search for the pattern in a longer string and return true i guess). Is there any other way to restrict  the length besides using ^ $?

Comment: Sure, with lookaheads, `^(?=.{6}$)....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first regex says:

```
Match a single character present in the list below [1-3]
Match a single character present in the list below [0-2]
Match a single character present in the list below [xs0]
Match a single character present in the list below [30Aa]
Match a single character present in the list below [xsu]
Match a single character present in the list below [.,] exactly six times.
```

Your second regex says:

```
^ asserts position at start of the string
Match a single character present in the list below [1-3]
Match a single character present in the list below [0-2]
Match a single character present in the list below [xs0]
Match a single character present in the list below [30Aa]
Match a single character present in the list below [xsu]
Match a single character present in the list below [.,]
$ asserts position at the end of the string, 
    or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```

So... Your first regex matches strings of length 11, and the second one matches strings of length 6.

`[abc]` is a group. It stands for `single a or b or c`. You can modify a group by adding:
`*`, `+` or `{}`.
`[abc]*` stands for `single character a or b or c, match 0 to inf times`. Will match for example:

- `a`
- `b`
- `abaa`
- `abcabcabcaaaaa`

`+` says `match at least one time`,
`{6}` says match exactly 6 times.

Comment: No need copy/pasting such machine-like explanations that can be easily obtained at https://regex101.com/r/Gn4NRk/1 and https://regex101.com/r/Gn4NRk/2.